# JavaFX remove separation between toolbar and top of window

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have a JavaFX app that atm is just a BorderPane with a ToolBar at the top.  It looks like this:

[image]

I was wondering whether there was a way to remove the line between the top of the window and the ToolBar so that it looks something like this:

[image]

I've already tried setting the ToolBar's border width and the BorderPane's border width to 0 but neither helped.

Comment: Are you using fxml?  If so, please post the fxml file.

Comment: I'm not using FXML.  Also I haven't been able to test out the proposed answer yet but I'll do so tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried amru's answer and it removed the line from the top of the toolbar.  Unfortunately, there was still a line at the bottom of the window decoration.  After spending a couple of hours researching this, I found that there's currently no way to do what I wanted to in JavaFX (without embedding the JavaFX in a swing window which isn't an option for other reasons) although it's a known issue and a fix is being worked on for a future release (see [here](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-19834)).

Answer (score 2):

The line is toolbar's first background color that is only shown 1px above and bottom of it. Checkout `-fx-background-insets` below

```
.tool-bar:horizontal {
    -fx-background: derive(-fx-base,-30%);
    -fx-background-color:
        linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-base,-30%), derive(-fx-base,-60%)),
        linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-base,65%) 2%, derive(-fx-base,-20%) 95%);
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 0 1 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0, 0 ;
    -fx-padding: 0.416667em 0.833em 0.416667em 0.833em; /* 5 10 5 10 */
    -fx-spacing: 0.333em; /* 4 */
    -fx-alignment: CENTER_LEFT;
}
```

To remove the top line, change the inset to:

```
-fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
```

To tweak default looks of JavaFX control's, I suggest to take a look at caspian.css file.

Comment: See my answer.  This helped but didn't completely fix the problem.  Thanks for trying, though.